# Is there a way to implement -ms-word-break: break-all; to an anchor tag?

Tags: html, css

It only works if I wrap the anchor tag with a different element, but I'm reading in the html so I want to add it as a style for the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here, some code snippets would be nice if you could share.

Anyway, I think - and I'm just poking about for an answer here in the dark - that you might have some confusion with inline or block displaying here and the word-break property itself.

The word-break property specifies how to break lines within words or whether even do it or not. Say you have a paragraph in a

tag, which is a block level element and you have words in it. Eventually, the paragraph element reaches and overcomes the width of it's parent element - say a  - at which point the paragraph goes into a new line. Here, the word-break property will specify how to render this break within the last word.

In your example, the anchor tag is an inline tag, which means it's width will by default get the width of it's content. Unless the word is so long that it's width is bigger than the anchor tag's parent, I really don't see how this would work.

Give me some more information about your issue and share your code so I'll be able to help you out.

Also, from [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/word-break):

> IE8 introduced -ms-word-break as a synonym for word-break. Don't use the -ms- prefix.

Comment: I have a windows 8 app and I'm populating the webview with html content read from an api.  So I'm stuck with the -ms prefix, as the webview is rendered in IE10.  Well, if there is a hyperlink that is really long with no whitespaces then it goes on and on and on and on and causes the layout of the webview to look like crap.

Comment: So I added the break-all style to any paragragh, and it works....sorta, but now it breaks words, all words.  Even if there is a nearby whitespace where the line could break.  So I just want to apply that style to any anchor tags.  However, the anchor elements don't seem to respect that style.

Comment: I'd really need to see the HTML and CSS codes so I could give you a better answer. For instance, are the anchors aligned horinzontally or vertically under each other, like a list? I'd try giving the word-break property to the parent element of the anchor tags, or set the display of the anchors to block and give the the word-break property of your choice. Please, post your code, I'll be able to give you a sure answer then, only guessing this way.